# Galaxy tab 2 7 inch picture distorted

Tags: android, camera

I wrote an app that takes picture using the Camera class. The problem is that the pictures taken on Galaxy tab 2 7 inch(running ICS) are distorted. It appear to be squished vertically. Has anybody run into this problem? And what is the solution? Other devices, including Galaxy S3 are fine.

Thanks
Ray

Comment: I'm taking photos in my app on a Tab 2 (7.0) too but not having issues, Android 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the fix. The problem is that as long as you set the camera parameters the images are distorted, however if I do not set it(preview size) the preview is distorted. The solution is to keep the default parameters when opening the camera, and set the default parameters back to the camera before taking the picture.
I have run into quite some problems with Samsung devices. They cause a lot of headache.